# Making different threads loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I’m new when it comes to threads and I’m having a problem running 2 threads at the same time with different sleep times.
What I have is this:

```
def function(browser):
    sendemail()

def secondfunction(browser):
    sendemail_2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 time=configs()
 while True:
  time=configs()
  if condition==True:
    x =threading.Thread(target=function,args=(browser,))
    x.start()
  if secondcondition==True:
    x =threading.Thread(target=function,args=(browser,))
    x.start()
  time.sleep(time)
```

Two different functions, in the main thread I do a while true so that the time of the sleep keeps getting updated and then when the first condition returns true it starts, sleeps inside the function and passes to the second condition that will now be true and runs again the thread, jumping then again to the time.sleep of the while true that is going to be different and keeps looping that. What I want it’s for the second thread that will have "secondfunction" as target to run and sleep every 5 minutes but if I do it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
 time=configs()
 while True:
  time=configs()
  if condition==True:
    x =threading.Thread(target=function,args=(browser,))
    x.start()
  if secondcondition==True:
    x =threading.Thread(target=function,args=(browser,))
    x.start()
  time.sleep(time)
 while True:
   y =threading.Thread(target=secondfunction,args=(browser,))
   y.start()
   time.sleep(300)
```

The first while true works but won’t let my script run the second while true. I need to make one thread sleep for an amount of time defined by the "time" variable and at the same time the second thread still running every 5 minutes, both in a loop with different sleep times.
How can i do it?

Comment: Please fix the capitalization of your code!

Comment: Sorry, fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate function for the second infinite loop and call it in a separate thread beforehand:

```
def second_function_loop():
  while True:
    secondfunction(browser)
    time.sleep(300)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  threading.Thread(target=second_function_loop).start()
  while True:
    time=configs()
    if condition:
      threading.Thread(target=function,args=(browser,)).start()
    if secondcondition:
      threading.Thread(target=function,args=(browser,)).start()
    time.sleep(time)
```